# How do I create a passphrase for Ethereum account on Alchemy/Infura?

Tags: infura

I want to run a livepeer node and for that I have to run a command:
`livepeer -network mainnet -ethUrl https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<project_id> -transcoder`

When I run the above command, replacing my project id with the placeholder, it asks me the following:
`Please enter the passphrase to unlock Ethereum account <eth_account>`

I created a free version from Alchemy and have not created any passphrase for my ETH account.

Exactly the same issue arose with Infura.

How to create a passphrase for ETH account or how to bypass this in order to run livepeer?

Comment: You don't. Infura or any other node provider does not support hosted accounts.

Comment: So, how would one connect to Ethereum as mentioned here(https://livepeer.org/docs/installation/connect-to-ethereum) ?

Comment: That's a question for Livepeer support